# Python, How to make a Video File(Mpeg/avi etc) into an exe?

Tags: c++, python, compiler-construction

First of all, I really don't know the correct direction on where to search or what to search.

Going to the point of problems.

How can I make my Video File into an exe format?

I really need your help guys, this is new to me.

I Have this Video file that need to be converted into an exe file.
That once I run it, it will play, and then add some condition to it that it can only be played once. If they try to play it again a message will appear that its expired.

Please help me, also if it's possible for other programming language to do this.

EDIT: 
I'M JUST TRYING TO DO SOMETHING ABOUT PIRACY!!! WE ARE AN INDEPENDENT SHORT MOVIE MAKER.

Comment: This sounds like a bad VWorker request...

Comment: If I downloaded a video file and it was an .exe I sure as hell wouldn't open it.

Comment: Virus worker? how about im just preventing PIRACY?

Comment: I remember working with a company that created 'executable' videos about 10 years ago (I was a codec developer at the time). Sorry, I forget all the details, but I remember arguing that it would never work (commercially, not technically) as sensible users wouldn't run an .exe to watch a single video.

Comment: If you make something of value and sell it at a price representive of that value piracy will be a minor issue. Look at louis ck's latest video.

Comment: You cannot make an executable self destruct like that (well you could, but then after running it once and it destroys itself I can just run the other identical copy I made before running it the first time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a video file into an executable.

You can write a video player in Python which implements the functionality you desire and then use something like py2exe to make it into an executable, but that would involve writing a video player in Python.

There is no programming language that will make a video into an executable file.

Comment: Hi there thanks for your informative answer, unlike those who's down vote the question without saying a thing. i got the trial program named "Video to EXE Converter" just google it, and you will see it, theres a 30day trial to it to, i just somehow needs to make a program like that, soo that makes me think its possible..

Comment: -1: It's perfectly possible to make an executable that only plays one video file. It's not a very good idea, but it's neither difficult nor original.

Comment: Well no. You're not making the Video into an exe. You're taking a video player and creating a one-off copy of that player which only plays back your video as it's sole asset. The video is NOT an executable but rather consumed by any executable.

Comment: @ tkone: Good point.  So at least two arguments against this approach: An .exe is an easy way to hide malware in a "video" and each video would be very large because of the extra "weight" of the player code.  Thanks for the useful comment.

Comment: that somehow clears the question in mind, by i wish i could understand more about this part ["You're taking a video player and creating a one-off copy of that player which only plays back your video as it's sole asset."], but really i appreciate this information you shared